# Selenium code to click/tap on a link, which opens a new tab on ipad/iphone

Tags: ios, selenium, tabs, click, saucelabs

I have been trying to **click/tap** on a link using selenium, which opens a new tab on **ipad/iphone**. The test, I have written is working fine on desktop but it is not clicking the element, when it runs on ipad/iphone (saucelab). The step, which clicks the element is Passed (no error) but the click is not happened and there is only one window handle (parent) available. When I try to click on the element manually (on saucelab as well on physical device), it works fine & the new tab opens. Tried with different locators & all identifies the element correctly. Tried with different methods like javascript, actions, TouchActions, long press & release and even send keys. I observed the same behavior in other sites as well.

It seems like a generic issue. Please help me to fix this.

**Similar scenario:** Verify clicking on the link 'Google’s Terms of Service' on page "https://www.google.com/gmail/about/policy/" opens a new tab.

**code segment**

```
    driverThread.get().get("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/policy/");
    String parentHandle = driverThread.get().getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("Parent Handle --- " + parentHandle);
    WebElement element = driverThread.get().findElement(By.cssSelector("body > main > section > section > div > p:nth-child(2) > a"));
    element.click();   // **please help me to click/tap this element**
    String newHandle = null;
    System.out.println("Window Handles size --- " + driverThread.get().getWindowHandles().size());
    for (String handle : driverThread.get().getWindowHandles()) {
         System.out.println("Handle --- " + handle);
         if(!handle.equalsIgnoreCase(parentHandle))
             newHandle = handle;
    }
    driverThread.get().switchTo().window(newHandle);
    System.out.println("New Tab URL --- "+ driverThread.get().getCurrentUrl());
```

Comment: Try to click the element with xpath locator. And after the click, use Assertion to verify the future element is present or not. Provide the link's HTML tag completely and I will try to frame xpath.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I have told, I have tried xpath, all locators are working fine on desktop but not on ipad/iphone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for clicking on the link :

```
WebElement element = driverThread.get().findElement(By.linkText("Google’s Terms of Service"));
element.click();
```

try out this code ! hope this will help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I have told, I have tried with different locators, all are working fine on desktop but not on ipad/iphone.

Comment: @Latha : it may be because of cssSelector that you have provided : body > main > section > section > div > p:nth-child(2) > a , you may opt for linkText ,did you try this one ?

Comment: Thanks for your support. Yes I have tried, it didn't work.